# Change the style of the hardkey menu panel using AppCompat & Material

Tags: android, android-theme, android-appcompat, android-menu, material-design

There are many questions about changing the text color or background image of the **hardkey menu** using ActionBarSherlock or other libraries. But I could not find any answer that worked with the Material theme using AppCompat.

So how do I change the text color and background for the **hardkey menu** panel?

*By default the panel looks like this (Light.DarkActionBar theme). I really dislike the ugly gray-to-gray contrast and I would like to change the text color to black.*

[image: default menu look]

Answer (score 5):

The AppCompat library uses the `Theme.AppCompat.CompactMenu` for the hardkey menu. The hardkey menu is always gray tinted by default it doesn't mater if you use a Light or Dark theme.

*Default 9-patch background:*

[image: Default 9-patch image for the hardkey menu]

Digging into the AppCmpat source it seems there are several attributes used in the base compat theme (`Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat`) to style the hardkey menu:

```
<item name="panelMenuListWidth">@dimen/abc_panel_menu_list_width</item>
<item name="panelMenuListTheme">@style/Theme.AppCompat.CompactMenu</item>
<item name="panelBackground">@drawable/abc_menu_hardkey_panel_mtrl_mult</item>
<item name="android:panelBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="listChoiceBackgroundIndicator">@drawable/abc_list_selector_holo_dark</item>
```

### Styling the background

Styling the background is actually pretty simple once you know how to do it. You just need to add the `panelBackground` attribute to your custom app theme.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    <item name="panelBackground">@drawable/yourCustomBackground</item>
</style>
```

### Styling the text

Styling the text is a bit more complicated. You need to create a custom `panelMenuListTheme` and set a `itemTextAppearance` to it.

```
<style name="Theme.YourTheme.CompactMenu" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.CompactMenu">
    <item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.YourTheme.Material.CompactMenu</item>
</style>

<style name="TextAppearance.YourTheme.Material.CompactMenu" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/yourCustomColor</item>
</style>
```

Then add your custom created `panelMenuListTheme` theme to your custom app theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    <item name="panelMenuListTheme">@style/Theme.YourTheme.CompactMenu</item>
</style>
```

### Result

*(The background property has not been altered in this example image)*

[image: Menu after styling]